# Can someone tell me where i can get the source code to create a simple Q&A forum using ASP.Net (Visual Studio 2005)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5

Can someone tell me where I can get source code to create a simple question answer forum by using ASP.Net (Visual Studio 2005) ?
As per the requirement I need to get a prototype for this type of question answer forum which can be used along with a Reporting application. 
I can use Visual studio 2005/2008. 
Infact, I may be given the liberty to use silverlight 3.

Comment: This may have not been your intention but the whole tone of this question comes across as slightly rude.

Comment: i didnt mean to be rude. if my tone seems rude to you then i apologise. but i m in a bit of an awkward situation. need to present a prototype by EOD :)

Comment: I fail to see how this question is rude in any possible way?

Comment: I agree with JL.. 1. Not everyone has a thorough comprehension of the English language, and they shouldnt be expected to. 2. this is a site for programmers to ask for and share technical knowledge, not for gentelmen to share niceties!

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at [Yet Another Forum](http://www.yetanotherforum.net/)